# Dell Vostro laptop - Assign special keys

Tags: keyboard, laptop

Dell Vostro laptop has three special keys. There is Dell software for windows - 'quickset' that allows to assign an action for those keys. But for Linux there seems to be no way to identify and assign the keys. However, one, 'settings' key works - it opens the 'start' menu in xfce (maybe kde5 too).

Can I somehow identify those special keys and assign them, for instance, the right key in that row to turn off/on the monitor?

[image: upper right corner]

Comment: You can run `xev` from a terminal to see low-level(-ish) data on keypresses. Do those keys generate any output there?

Comment: Install `xev` and try again.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz those two special keys generate nothing for xev

Answer (score 1):

In order to map rare or custom key bindings you will need to manually edit [xmodmap](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/xmodmap.1.html) and ensure that it boots every time X starts.

If [xev](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man1/xev.1.xhtml) is not working, you can also run `showkey --keycodes`
When I ran `showkey --keycodes` it returned an error

> Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console

So I had to run `showkey --ascii` and use the first column number, the decimal number in this case 97
`a   97 0141 0x61` and [convert it to a hex number](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-binary.html)  which returned a confirmed and correct value of 61 for key a, which is what xev returned as well as seen below.

Now start an X session, just log into your xfce desktop environment and run xev. A small window will pop up and the terminal will start outputting data for every key interaction that is received from the keyboard.

Here is the output that xev generated when I pressed the a key and when I released the key.

```
KeyPress event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x2400001,
    root 0x13e, subw 0x0, time 5887747, (622,717), root:(633,745),
    state 0x0, keycode 38 (keysym 0x61, a), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (61) "a"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (61) "a"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x2400001,
    root 0x13e, subw 0x0, time 5887843, (622,717), root:(633,745),
    state 0x0, keycode 38 (keysym 0x61, a), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (61) "a"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Now, when pressing a key that is not mapped it will return a NoSymbol value following the keycode number.

Everytime you identify a NoSymbol key, note the keycode number.

```
KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    root 0x38, subw 0x0, time 636666629, (158,102), root:(832,903),
    state 0x10, keycode 164 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:  ""
```

Once you identified and noted all the keycode that return a NoSymbol,

Enter

```
$ xmodmap -pke > xmodmap.conf
```

Which will write the current keyboard map to xmodmap.conf.

Now you will have to edit xmodmap.conf and assign a [XF86 keyboard symbol](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/XF86_keyboard_symbols) to the keycode.

Any free XF86 keyboard symbol will do as long as it's not in use.

`keycode 164 = XF86Music`

save the edited xmodmap.conf file

Add it to autostart every time X runs.

`echo 'xmodmap xmodmap.conf' >> ~/.xinitrc`

and you can enter 
`xmodmap xmodmap.conf`
to bypass the need to reboot, and just reload xmodmap right away and enjoy your newly mapped keyboard keys.

Comment: thank you for the try. However, the problem here is that those two special non-keyboard keys cannot be read. There are no codes for them (showkey, xev), unlike for the rest of the keys. Let's put it this way: we need a "driver" for those keys. https://www.notebookcheck.net/fileadmin/_migrated/pics/IMG_6994_1600.jpg -- right, upper corner, two right keys. still, somehow in xfce the left key out of those 3 opens the start menu, prints nothing for `showkey` and prints somedata for `xev`

Comment: Which model of Vostro? Please look on the underside for the Service Tag, click [edit] under your original question, and add it to the original question so we can dig deeper.